# sh: Rscript: command not found

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, pydev

`Rscript` doesn't work when calling it from a `Python` script in `PyDev`.

Here's the guilty code:

```
os.system("Rscript --vanilla test.R")
```

And the error:

```
sh: Rscript: command not found
```

Comment: put it in your PATH...

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisFabre I should have mentioned that it works if i run this from the terminal.

Comment: try `which Rscript` in your terminal (are you using windows or Linux)

Comment: Mac `/usr/local/bin/Rscript`

Comment: can you try your syscall with full path? `os.system("/usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla test.R")` ?

Comment: I suggest using the Rpy2 library if you want to integrate python and R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a mac the command is just `system`:

```
> system("Rscript --vanilla test.R")
[1] " Your Name is    and  you are     years old"
```

(My test.R (in my working directory) was left over from a prior question.) Rscript should have been installed during "regular" installation from the CRAN dmg in the "usual" place, as your appears to be and mine is.